# Get status of an ongoing docker image pull

Tags: docker, status, pull

How to get status of a running docker pull process? I tried pulling busybox with `sudo docker pull busybox` . But no status is being displayed. On issuing another pull request after a ctrl+c it says that image is already being pulled by another client.Also I tried cancelling the ongoing pull and I couldnt [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1046717) is a bug report regarding the issue.

```
$sudo docker pull busybox
Repository busybox already being pulled by another client. Waiting.
```

How can I display the progress of an ongoing docker pull?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This wasn't available at the time the question was asked (2015)

Now, if you run the same `docker pull` in two windows you see the same status, i.e. which layers are being downloaded, how far it got, etc.

If you kill just one of those two `docker pull` commands, the other one carries on.

If you kill the last client that requested a `pull`, the `pull` operation terminates.

[original answer follows...]

This is a proposed feature of Docker.  See ongoing discussion at https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6928:

> My proposal is as follows.
>
> - `docker pull --list` to list all the current running docker pulls
> - `docker pull --resume` to resume a given pull
> - `docker pull --rm` to remove a given pull

Comment: The `--list` `--resum` and `--rm` seems deprecated in `v1.9.0`. How to rm the pull in v1.9.0?

Comment: these options are deprecated

Comment: @pablo-morales It was a _proposal_; as far as I can see it was never implemented.  I updated my answer - looks like the fix is in Docker 1.10.

Comment: @Bryan Just pointing to a github issue isn't enough for this to be a good answer.

Comment: If you're trying to get the status of the download or upload in Java you can create a Data Transfer Object (DTO) and return that while the actual download is happening so the user knows the status of the docker interaction.

Answer (score -4):

I think you are behind a proxy. If so, you have to stop docker and start it by the following command

```
sudo HTTP_PROXY=http://<ip of proxy server:port> docker -d &
```

unset http_proxy and export http_proxy did not work for me while working with docker.